# Jquery : Setting selected state on select option items populated via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectbox

I have 6 select boxes (sbs), 3 to a row so two rows. The top three sbs contain a list of options that gets populated via php, data is pulled back from mysql. When an option from each box is selected I'm using jquery (via ajax) to pull back option items for the sb immediately below it and populate said sb with corresponding data. I click 'create' and the data is sent via ajax to a php script which then stores the data in a table and returns the submited dropdown data (albeit formatted) in a table below the form. So you might have something that looks like this after creating a 'combination'. Eveyrthying to the left of the colon was an option on the top row of select boxes and then you have selected options from the corresponding box below displayed to the right.

```
Color: Red    |   Capacity : 4GB    |      Model : ABC    |    EDIT
Color: Blue   |       Speed: 2GHZ   |   Capacity : 2GB    |    EDIT
```

etc.

If I want to edit the record I click edit and jquery finds the id of the edit button clicked, passes it via ajax to another php script which then returns a json object with the relevant data and this is then used to repopulate the dropdown boxes with the selected options. Everything so far works fine.

My problem is this, only the top row of sbs get one of the options selected when edit is clicked. The child options don't get selected and I can't figure out why. I can get the right options to display but can't set the selected state for whatever matching value is returned in my json object. I've been 8 hours trying to figure it out and tried various things on SOverflow and other sites, none of worked - i'm not that experienced with javascript/ajax to be honest.

Upon a successful ajax process i.e success: I am doing the following:

```
var jObj = $.parseJSON(html);

//parentVariations# is the select boxes in the top row where 
//Color, capacity, model options are displayed.
//The trigger fires off my ajax function which is responsible for 
//populating the corresponding child select box with relevant data.

$('#parentVariations1').val(jObj.groupAttr1).trigger('change'); 
$('#parentVariations2').val(jObj.groupAttr2).trigger('change'); 
$('#parentVariations3').val(jObj.groupAttr3).trigger('change'); 

//childVariations# is the child option box, i have the same code for each child
//box but am only showing the first one here for simplicitys sake.
//What I thought I was doing here is getting each option then if the value 
//matches that held in my corresponding json object set that option to selected...
//Doesn't work :'(
$("#childVariations1 option").each(function()
{
if($(this).val() == jObj.childAttr1)
{
      $("#childVariations1 option").attr('selected','selected');
}
});
```

Any help would be very welcome as it's driven me over the edge.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#childVariations1 option")` is an array of all the options. You need to specify which one:

```
$("#childVariations1 option").eq(1).attr('selected','selected');
```

If your case, use a `for` loop and use the index for get the current position, instead of using `.each`. (or set up a counter)

Comment: Thanks for your help Diodeus, I believe your solution works however I think that something is overwriting the selected state. If I click the edit button repeatedly and rapidly I can see the select box being updated with the correctly selected item but then it gets overwritten with the first option in the box which is 'please choose'. I have noticed that if I add an alert(''); immediately before the for loop then everything works fine.

Comment: Try to post your code on jsfiddle.net and I will take a look at it.